# How to =VLOOKUP based on multiple fragmented criterion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a google spreadsheet with a master data sheet that kind of looks like this

[image: Master Sheet Example]

And I want to parse this data based on multiple criteria to populate a dashboard that looks like this
[image]

Which means my search key would have to break apart the first column, reconcat that into the header row, then search against the example district in one column, and search against the concatenated role in another role, just to pull someones first name.

I think I understand in concept that I should be doing that, I just can't figure out a formula to do all of that without changing the current sheet too much.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) with some info on how you arrived at that specific output you mentioned so that it gives a clear picture for us to work it out

Comment: Split, filter, concatenate. "Example Youth Club" - will street name always be 1 word at beggining? How to know if you are looking for "Youth Club" in "Example" street and not "Club" in "Example youth" street?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`=query({arrayformula(substitute(query({query({byrow(A1:B,lambda(r,textjoin(" ",true,r))),C1:C,D1:D},"select Col1, Col2 where not Col2 contains 'Vice' and Col2 contains 'President'");query({byrow(A1:B,lambda(r,textjoin(" ",true,r))),C1:C,D1:D},"select Col1, Col3 where not Col3 contains 'Vice' and Col3 contains 'President'")},"select Col2"),"President","")),query({query({byrow(A1:B,lambda(r,textjoin(" ",true,r))),C1:C,D1:D},"select Col1, Col2 where not Col2 contains 'Vice' and Col2 contains 'President'");query({byrow(A1:B,lambda(r,textjoin(" ",true,r))),C1:C,D1:D},"select Col1, Col3 where not Col3 contains 'Vice' and Col3 contains 'President'")},"select Col2, Col1 where Col1 is not null")},"select Col1,  Col3")`

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: sample data]

**RESULTS**

[image: results]